# Signing webhooks: symmetric vs asymmetric

Tags: cryptography, http

I want to sign webhooks so that client services can verify that a request came from my service.

Looking around, it seems that most SaaS use symmetric keys shared by the client and the SaaS. Obviously, there's an overhead of generating and storing a unique secret for each client here.

It seems to me like asymmetric crypto is an easier solution here: sign the payload with a private key, publish the public key on your website, and you avoid the overhead of maintaining shared secrets for each client.

Given the above, is there a good reason many reputable SaaS (GitHub, Stripe, Slack etc.) opt for using shared secrets for signing webhooks? What are the tradeoffs of the approaches?

Answer (score 1):

**Asymmetric encryption** is more useful when communication is *with untrusted parties* since you can keep the private key safe while sharing the public key more loosely.

**Symmetric** is more useful *between trusted parties* as the key is needs to be more secure.

So if the purpose of the webhook is to integrate a *trusted* application to post messages to your Slack channel, symmetric encryption is fine.

Comment: "the key ... needs to be more secure" -- not quite. The key needs to be communicated securely and stored and managed securely on both ends. Asymmetric keys only need to be secured on the private end and the public key does not need to be communicated or secured at all. The key itself does not need to be more secure than the other.

Comment: "a trusted application" -- again, not *quite*. Given the above correction, it's not about *trust* it's about *control*. If you control and can protect both ends, using a symmetric key is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's 2 reasons for this, preventing replay attacks, and key rotation.

With Github for example, it signs the message payload using HMAC-SHA256, and then places the signature on a header value, which can be verified by the hook endpoint.

A replay attack is simple enough, I generate a few webhook calls to my API, and since they're all signed by the same key, I can take those same payloads and use them to call your webhook, and it will at least pass the first authentication step.

You could check certain fields in the payload (e.g. the repositories full name) to ensure these are really 'your' webhook calls, but message types can be different depending on the event -- it's much easier to authenticate the message by checking one signature that's always found in a known HTTP-header, then it is to parse different message formats trying to extract these fields. More importantly, it's always a good idea to authenticate **first** and then process the message, authentication of a message based on a public key isn't really 'authentication' in this case, as I could easily impersonate it.

The second reason is key rotation, having just one key for ALL Github webhooks is a phenomenally bad idea! Should that key get compromised, an attacker could impersonate GitHub on **any** Webhook.

Worse yet, imagine if 5 years from now, GitHub wants to swap the public key -- now every GitHub webhook needs to change in a co-ordinated fashion, not easy when you have millions of webhooks. By having user-defined keys, Github has pushed the key rotation maintenance onto the users (as they should), and let the user define their own key rotation policy (which could be never!).